# How do i remove the error in my R profit model?

Tags: r

My current code:

```
library(AER)
data("HMDA")
View(HMDA)


HMDA$denyDum <- (HMDA$deny == "yes")*1

HMDA$Black <- (HMDA$afam == "yes")*1

probit2 <- glm(denyDum ~ pirat+ Black , data = HMDA , family = binomial(link = "probit"))
summary(probit2)

predict(probit2 , data.frame(pirat = .7) , type = "response")
```

I am trying to find the probability of denial changes (`denyDum`) between a `black` and `non-black` applicant if both have payment to income ratio of `0.7`.

I received the error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'Black' not found"

Even though I have defined the variable black. Any clue what I can do to fix this?

Comment: You defined `Black` in the `HMDA` frame, yes ... but you didn't in your call to `predict`. Perhaps `predict(probit2, data.frame(pirat=0.7, Black=0), type="response")`.

Comment: This did result in removing the error, but it also spits out the same number when I ran my predict(logit) model. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Ahhhh ... (1) it depends on how you defined the `logit` model (not included here), but more importantly, (2) that question is much more suited for [stats.se], not SO, as it relates to the *math* of the problem. In general, though, even though they pull from different distributions (probit from cumulative std normal, logit from logistic distribution), they both map onto `[0,1]`, so it's feasible that their results will be close to the same. Are you referencing https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/11-2-palr.html?